# Split on whitespace and pick second item

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to do a `"red L".split(' ')[1]` entirely in regex.

So far I have `"red L".match(/(?=\s).+/)` which returns `" L"` with a leading whitespace.

How do I move it past the whitespace for the match?

Comment: is there a good reason for doing this only in regular expression...?

Comment: Yes, needs to be super flexible config without any hard-coding :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match the first space and capture non-spaces that follow, then get the captured group:

```js
console.log(
  'red L'.match(/ (\S+)/)[1]
);
```

On very modern browsers that support lookbehind, you can use lookbehind too:

```js
console.log(
  'red L'.match(/(?<= )\S+/)
);
```

Comment: I think the OP wanted to handle the white space via RegEx.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this way with regex: `"red L".match(/ (\w+)/)[1]`.

Basically this means... Match on a  space, then capture `()` a `\w` word character that appears `+` one or more times.